# Python Thread Error , Twitch Script

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am running this script , but I can not seem to get it working any ideas? I run it like python filename.py 10 10 , but it returns with "thread error" which its suppose to print i assume as it is in the code. How can I fix this?

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json
import sys
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue

numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
builderThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
startTime = time.time()
numberOfSockets = 0
concurrent = 25
urls = []
urlsUsed = []

def getURL(): # Get tokens
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/The_XPZ", "-j"],     stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
  return json.loads(output)['streams']['worst']['url'] # Parse json and return the URL parameter

def build(): # Builds a set of tokens, aka viewers
    global numberOfSockets
    global numberOfViewers
    while True:
        if numberOfSockets < numberOfViewers:
            numberOfSockets += 1
            print "Building viewers " + str(numberOfSockets) + "/" + str(numberOfViewers)
            urls.append(getURL())

def view(): # Opens connections to send views
    global numberOfSockets
    while True:
        url=q.get()
        requests.head(url)
        if (url in urlsUsed):
            urls.remove(url)
            urlsUsed.remove(url)
            numberOfSockets -= 1
        else:
            urlsUsed.append(url)
        q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, builderThreads):
        threading.Thread(target = build).start()

    while True:
        while (numberOfViewers != numberOfSockets): # Wait until sockets are built
            time.sleep(1)

        q=Queue(concurrent*2)
        for i in range(concurrent):
            try:
                t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                t.daemon=True
                t.start()
            except:
                print 'thread error'
        try:
            for url in urls:
                print url
                q.put(url.strip())
                q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(1)
```

[Traceback screenshot](http://puu.sh/6DbUz.png)

Comment: Can you give us the full traceback?

Comment: the original code is here https://gist.github.com/Xeroday/6468146/raw/1b7fb468551a4ba5b73ea3c0b7bc47591c3a8c51/Twitch.py

Comment: As in, the full error message you get when trying to run the script.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\viewerbotpy", line 9, in <module>
        numberOfViewers = int(sys.argv[1])
    IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Well, that's definitely not a Threading error.

Comment: Did you get this error by running, like you said, `python filename.py 10 10`?

Comment: Well that error is because I run it via Python GUI with no commands , If i run it via command line and do python filename.py 10 10 or whatever numbers it returns with thread error and continues printing it , as it says at the bottom of the code

Comment: yes , by running it like filename.py 10 10

Comment: You need to post the error you get when running your script with the two arguments. Specifically, this `thread error` you're talking about, because the error you posted is an `IndexError`.

Comment: Can you add me via skype? chris.payne282 , it would make this easier

Comment: I don't have skype, apologies. I'm also not sure if I'd be able to help you, but you'd need to add the full traceback of the Thread Error to your question so that others can better assist you.

Comment: how can i add the full traceback? i run it via command line and i can't copy and paste the error because all it says in thread error lol

Comment: Ah, thread error isn't an actual exception, it's a string printed in your program. Why don't you remove the `try/except` block so we can see exactly what went wrong when attempting to start the thread. Then, print the full traceback.

Comment: how should i do this, can i have an example?

Comment: try:
                t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                t.daemon=True
                t.start()
            except:
                print 'thread error'

remove the try and except part. Just have the information contained in the try block. Then, Python will throw a more specific error similar to the `IndexError` you pasted earlier.

Comment: only remove that? , or should i remove `try:
    t=threading.Thread(target=view)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()
   except:
    print 'thread error'
  try:
   for url in urls:
    print url
    q.put(url.strip())
    q.join()`

Comment: Ah, yeah, remove them all. We're trying to figure out exactly where the error occurs and what is happening.

Comment: `q=Queue(concurrent*2)
  for i in range(concurrent):
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
   sys.exit(1)` It says and unexpected indent and it highlights red "except"

Comment: edit your question with your changed code. You just have some formatting problems, but it's probably not the thread error you're looking for.

Comment: okay, if you look at the original coding.. i removed `while True:
        while (numberOfViewers != numberOfSockets): # Wait until sockets are built
            time.sleep(1)

        q=Queue(concurrent*2)
        for i in range(concurrent):
            try:
                t=threading.Thread(target=view)
                t.daemon=True
                t.start()
            except:
                print 'thread error'
        try:
            for url in urls:
                print url
                q.put(url.strip())
                q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:`

Comment: You can edit your original question. Just copy over the changed code, because it's hard to tell what you've changed in a comment.

Comment: Here is the new error, http://puu.sh/6DbUz.png

Comment: also , here is the current coding now http://puu.sh/6DbWn.png

Comment: You're trying to access a URL?

Answer (score 0):

You're not encountering an error with your `Threading` implementation, at least right now. The problem is that your `try/except` block catches every single type of error and prints "Thread error" regardless of what it is.

[`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is not designed for opening urls. Windows is throwing an error because the URL/network information you're specifying is not a local file or valid command.

Rather, you need to look into a library like [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html) or [`Requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), designed to get information through HTTP requests. Assuming you're expecting json data, you can then use the `json` library to decode it. So, for example:

```
import urllib2

def getURL():
    output = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.twitch.tv/The_XPZ') # Any URL
    return json.load(response)['streams']['worst']['url']
```

It's not clear from your code exactly what URL you're trying to access, but you can substitute what you need.